# Add user input to Excel table upon upload to Access database

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I'm trying to combine user inputs with existing Excel file data so they will all be included in a single table when they are uploaded to the Access database.

Here is the way I have it laid out, but I'm open to changing it however need be.

[image]

I'm just completely stuck with what to do next. Upload Date is automatically filled in, but the rest of the parameters will vary based on the product and will have to be filled in manually. I also want it to be mandatory that every field is filled in, so have an error message saying "Enter all parameters" or something like that if they aren't, which wouldn't allow the upload to be completed.

The reason why this is necessary to do in Access and simply not Excel is because the Excel file is generated by AutoCad Electrical and is limited in what data it can include. I tried adding the columns in Excel and importing them and it worked, but my boss said we NEED the user input box to make things easier.

This is the code I have to import the Excel file and add it to the correct table (_MCL UPLOAD). Now I just want to be able to have the user inputs add to this table as extra columns:

```
Private Sub ImportMCL_Click()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
'disable ms access warnings
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

'load spreadsheet
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 8, "_MCL UPLOAD", selectFile(), True
MsgBox "MCL Imported Successfully!"
're-enable ms access warnings
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "There was an Error: " & Err & ": " & Error(Err)


End Sub

Function selectFile()
Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd
    If .Show Then
        selectFile = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        'stop execution if nothing selected
        End
    End If
End With

Set fd = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Assuming that `Private Sub ImportMCL_Click()` is within the form code for your input, you should be able to check the values of any textboxes by adding a line that checks if any `TextBoxName.Value = ""` and using that to prompt a user?

Comment: So do you need help with just the data validations on the form? Or, do you need the inputs in the form to effect which data is imported into Access (e.g. a filter for which data is imported)?

Comment: Seems you have 2 issues: 1.) require values in the form's text boxes 2.) add the text box values as extra columns to the data you import from Excel.  If that is correct, I suggest you narrow the scope of this question.  Pick one issue and alter your question based on guidance from [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RyanWildry I need the inputs from the form to be shown, in the same table, with the uploaded data.

Comment: Perhaps run an Alter Table statement to add the columns you need, then run an update query with the form values. Also, you should perform the data validation (e.g. if me.MyControl <> "" then ...) up front and present a message box when something isn't filled out.

Comment: That seems like it could work. I'm looking at the examples here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196148.aspx, but my only concern is that when I do multiple uploads, it'll keep on adding the same columns instead of adding data to the columns I've already created. Does that make sense?

Comment: @HansUp, currently the priority is just getting the user inputted data to show up in my table. I already have columns created in the table where I want the information to go, I just don't know how to link it and get it there

Comment: No, the uploaded Excel file names will be different every time, but the column names within the table will be the same. If you're referring to the Sheet name at the bottom of the Excel Workbook, the default is always Sheet 1 and that will not change from file to file. Does that answer your question?

Comment: After `TransferSpreadsheet`, run an `UPDATE` query to load the text box values into the empty table fields.

Comment: @HansUp Thank you very much!! I can't believe I didn't think of that, it works perfectly

Comment: @HansUp, there actually is still a problem. If I import many files consecutively, the update query works "too well" in that it fills in ALL of the columns with the new Serial Number, SA Number etc instead of only updating the most recent data. I should be able to put something in the Criteria row of the Update Query, but I don't know what. Thank you again

Comment: Sounds like you're doing `TransferSpreadsheet` several times and then doing your `UPDATE` just once.  Do the `UPDATE` after each `TransferSpreadsheet`

Comment: @HansUp This is the way I have it set up in my VB:
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 8, "_MCL_UPLOAD", selectFile(), True

DoCmd.OpenQuery "UpdateMCL"

MsgBox "MCL Imported Successfully!"

So, I don't think its a syntax error, I think I just need to change my query criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final code looks like this:

```
'Import MCL Files Code
Private Sub ImportMCL_Click()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
'disable ms access warnings
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

'load spreadsheet in .xls format
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 8, "_MCL_UPLOAD", selectFile(), True
DoCmd.OpenQuery "UpdateMCL"
Call InsertInto_MASTER_UPLOAD
Call Delete_MCL_UPLOAD
MsgBox "MCL Imported Successfully!"
're-enable ms access warnings
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "There was an Error: " & Err & ": " & Error(Err)

End Sub

'Function called in Import MCL Code above
Function selectFile()
Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd
    If .Show Then
        selectFile = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        'stop execution if nothing selected
        End
    End If
End With

Set fd = Nothing
End Function

'Function Used to Delete MCL Uploaded file after it's moved to Master Table
Sub Delete_MCL_UPLOAD()

Dim dbs As Database, rst As Recordset

' Modify this line to include the path to Northwind
' on your computer.
Set dbs = OpenDatabase("default_cat.mdb")

' Delete employee records where title is Trainee.
dbs.Execute "DELETE * FROM " _
    & "_MCL_UPLOAD "

dbs.Close

End Sub

'Function Appends _MCL UPLOAD into the _MASTER_UPLOAD table
Sub InsertInto_MASTER_UPLOAD()

Dim dbs As Database

' Modify this line to include the path to Northwind
' on your computer.
Set dbs = OpenDatabase("default_cat.mdb")

' Select all records in the New Customers table
' and add them to the Customers table.
dbs.Execute " INSERT INTO _MASTER_UPLOAD " _
    & "SELECT * " _
    & "FROM [_MCL_UPLOAD];"

dbs.Close

End Sub
```

I basically created another table to dump all of the combined information into. Thanks for all of your help!