# Make all fields mandatory to be filled in

Tags: ms-access, vba

This question is continued from here: [Add user input to Excel table upon upload to Access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37659495/add-user-input-to-excel-table-upon-upload-to-access-database)

Now that I have my fields connected to a table in my database, I want to make sure that everyone fills them in. Upon clicking the Import button, I want to check the fields (SANumber, SerialNumber, CustomerName, and LyoSize) to make sure it will be a 'valid upload'.

I have this code so far:

```
Function CheckInputs() As Boolean

If Me.SANumber.value Or Me.SerialNumber.value Or Me.CustomerName.value Or Me.LyoSize.value = Null Then
 CheckInputs = True
Else
 CheckInputs = False
End If

 End Function

'Import MCL Files Code
Private Sub ImportMCL_Click()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
'disable ms access warnings
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

Call CheckInputs
If CheckInputs = True Then
MsgBox "All inputs must be entered!"
Exit Sub
Else

'load spreadsheet in .xls format
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 8, "_MCL_UPLOAD", selectFile(), True
DoCmd.OpenQuery "UpdateMCL"
Call InsertInto_MASTER_UPLOAD
Call Delete_MCL_UPLOAD
MsgBox "MCL Imported Successfully!"
're-enable ms access warnings
DoCmd.SetWarnings True    
End If

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "There was an Error: " & Err & ": " & Error(Err)

End Sub
```

It should work, but keeps on giving me the

> ERROR: 13. Type Mismatch

Comment: Error On which line ?

Comment: I'm assuming it's somewhere in the CheckInputs() function, but nothing specifically is showing up in the debugger. When all the input fields are empty, it happily accepts the upload, but when I have them all filled in (the way they're supposed to be), I get this error.

Comment: Add a break point on "If Me.SANumber.Value or....".  When the code pauses, check the value of all of those fields in the Immediate window and see if any give you specific errors.  If they do, that info would be helpful for us to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specifically check each field for null - you cannot do it this way:

```
If Me.SANumber.value Or Me.SerialNumber.value Or _
   Me.CustomerName.value Or Me.LyoSize.value = Null Then
```

Something like

```
If IsNull(Me.SANumber) Or IsNull(SerialNumber) Or _
   IsNull(Me.CustomerName) Or IsNull(Me.LyoSize) = Null Then
```

You should rename your function to something like "EmptyInputs" to make your code a little more self-documenting. "CheckInputs" is a little non-descriptive.

Comment: I just changed it to: Me.SANumber.value = Null Or Me.SerialNumber.value = Null Or Me.CustomerName.value = Null Or Me.LyoSize.value = Null ... I no longer get the error now, but the code totally glances over the function (it still accepts the import if none of the values are filled in)

Comment: This works perfectly. Was the issue maybe because I had Me.*.value ? I also changed the function name. Thank you!

Comment: Your code only tested the *last* field for Null - all of the other fields were just effectively tested for "truthiness" (I'm not that familiar with Access so I couldn't say exactly what that would mean in practice)

Answer (score 1):

You CheckInputs() functions logic is incorrect.  Or will return true if any one condition is meet.  
To get your desired result you can either ask does: 
If Condition1 = true AND Condition2 = true AND ....
 
Otherwise you can ask If Condition1 = false OR Condition2 = false OR ....
Try this....

```
Function isFormValid() As Boolean

    If isTextFieldInvalid(Me.SANumber) Or isTextFieldInvalid(Me.SerialNumber) Or isTextFieldInvalid(Me.CustomerName.Value) Or Me.LyoSize.Value = Null Then
        isFormValid = False
    Else
        isFormValid = True
    End If

End Function

Function isTextFieldInvalid(FieldControl) As Boolean
    If Not IsNull(FieldControl) Then
        If Len(Trim(FieldControl.Value)) Then
            isFieldValid = True
        End If
    End If
End Function

'Import MCL Files Code
Private Sub ImportMCL_Click()

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    'disable ms access warnings
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    If isFormValid Then
        MsgBox "All inputs must be entered!"
        Exit Sub
    Else

        'load spreadsheet in .xls format
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 8, "_MCL_UPLOAD", selectFile(), True
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "UpdateMCL"
        Call InsertInto_MASTER_UPLOAD
        Call Delete_MCL_UPLOAD
        MsgBox "MCL Imported Successfully!"
        're-enable ms access warnings
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    End If

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "There was an Error: " & Err & ": " & Error(Err)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you're clearing out afterwards by going something like SANumber = "" then testing for Nulls might not work.  I'd check for both nulls and blanks.  This is a general template you could use.

```
Dim LResponse As Integer
If (Nz(Me.SANumber.Value) = "") Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a SA Number.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
ElseIf (Nz(Me.SerialNumber.Value) = "") Then
   MsgBox "Please enter a Serial Number.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"

'All criteria met
Else
    LResponse = MsgBox("Would you like to submit? ", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Question")
    If LResponse = vbYes Then
        'enter code here
    ElseIf LResponse = vbNo Then
        MsgBox ("Not submitted.")
    End If
End If
```